# Node.JS IPFS sending message TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publish')

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I'm trying to send a message through an IPFS network but I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publish')`.

The error occurs at line `node.pubsub.publish(topic, msg, (err) => {})`.

`ipfs.js` is the app's main engine and contains the methods needed to interact with the IPFS network.

The 'sendNewMsg' method is used to send messages to a topic where other peers can subscribe and read the messages.

`index.js` calls and executes the method.

Could you please help me spot and fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

ipfs.js:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
const BufferPackage = require('buffer');

const Buffer = BufferPackage.Buffer;

class IPFSEngine {

    constructor(){
        let node = IPFS.create({
            EXPERIMENTAL: { pubsub: true },
            repo: (() => `repo-${Math.random()}`)(),
            config: {
                Addresses: {
                    Swarm: [
                        '/dns4/ws-star.discovery.libp2p.io/tcp/443/wss/p2p-websocket-star'
                    ]
                }
            }
        });

        this.node = node;
    }

    ....
    ....
    ....

    sendNewMsg(topic, newMsg) {
        let {node} = this;
        console.log('Message sent: ', newMsg)
        const msg = Buffer.from(newMsg)
        node.pubsub.publish(topic, msg, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(`Failed to publish to ${topic}`, err)
            }
            // msg was broadcasted
            console.log(`Published to ${topic}`)
        })
    }
}

// Export IPFSEngine
module.exports = {IPFSEngine};
```

index.js:

```
const {IPFSEngine} = require('./ipfs');

const ipfs = new IPFSEngine();

ipfs.sendNewMsg(`topic2`,`Messages 2 ..!`)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error states that `node.pubsub` is undefined while you are trying to access the `publish` property on the object.

Quickly reading through an [example from the IPFS documentation](https://github.com/ipfs-examples/js-ipfs-examples/tree/master/examples/ipfs-101), it appears that `IPFS.create` is an asynchronous API, which result you are not awaiting. It could explain why you get an undefined `pubsub` property on your node.

Using an async function, you could write something like:

```js
async function sendNewMsg(topic, newMsg) {
  let { node } = this;
  console.log('Message sent: ', newMsg);
  const msg = Buffer.from(newMsg);
  (await node).pubsub.publish(topic, msg, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(`Failed to publish to ${topic}`, err);
    }
    // msg was broadcasted
    console.log(`Published to ${topic}`);
  });
}
```

Or without the async/await syntax:

```js
function sendNewMsg2(topic, newMsg) {
  let { node } = this;
  console.log('Message sent: ', newMsg);
  const msg = Buffer.from(newMsg);
  node.then((readyNode) => {
    readyNode.pubsub.publish(topic, msg, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(`Failed to publish to ${topic}`, err);
      }
      // msg was broadcasted
      console.log(`Published to ${topic}`);
    });
  })
}
```